# What is the Interaction of Timeouts and Intervals in Pacemaker Resource Monitor Operations

Tags: pacemaker

If I have a pacemaker resource like this:

```
     Resource: FoobarServer (class=ocf provider=foo type=bar)
  Operations: monitor interval=5m timeout=8m (FoobarServer-monitor-interval-5m)
              start interval=0 timeout=360s (FoobarServer-start-0)
              stop interval=0 timeout=360s (FoobarServer-stop-0)
```

It seems that there would be a conflict given that the timeout is longer than the interval. However, I cannot find any documentation which specifically warns about this potential condition.

Is a different monitor process spawned every 5m which dies 8m later? Or is a single process restarted every 5m and (in this case) it will miss events which happen in the 3m difference between the interval and timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation available at Red Hat (which along SUSE is a main sponsor for [ClusterLabs](https://clusterlabs.org/)' pacemaker/corosync):

[RHEL8 - Chapter 20. Resource monitoring operations](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_resource-monitoring-operations-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters):

> `interval`
>
> [...]
> A recurring monitor action will be executed immediately after a
> resource start completes, and **subsequent monitor actions are scheduled
> starting at the time the previous monitor action completed**. For
> example, if a monitor action with interval=20s is executed at
> 01:00:00, the next monitor action does not occur at 01:00:20, but at
> 20 seconds after the first monitor action completes.

> `timeout`
>
> If the operation does not complete in the amount of time set by this
> parameter, abort the operation and consider it failed.
> [...]

So to summarize:

- there won't be any two overlapping monitoring actions: the interval is *after completion of the previous*, not *after start*. Successive monitoring actions can happen between 5mn and 13mn. In OP's case, in an hour of elapsed time there could be between 4 (1h/(5mn+8mn)) and 12 (1h/5mn) triggered monitoring actions, depending on the time it takes for the monitor to complete its check,
- even if the *interval* is a divisor of an hour, the monitor event will not happen at fixed times (like 12 times here) within an hour but will drift,
- depending on how the resource and monitor is implemented, that means the whole *interval* time, 5mn, of events could be missed if these events aren't queued somewhere to stay available for processing by the monitor,
- anyway if the failure happened immediately after the last *interval*, there will be almost *interval* time before having a chance to detect the failure,
- the *timeout* is the *maximum* time allowed for the monitoring action to finish but can be shorter,
- the monitor's role is to return a status when its action starts. It's not supposed to "keep monitoring" for 8mn. 8mn for *monitor timeout* looks like a dubious value, both compared to the *interval* value and in absolute value,
- while it appears logical that an action is a new spawned process, this information is not documented, so might be implementation/monitor specific. It doesn't matter much since there won't be two overlapping monitoring actions.

Comment: I was completely off track looking at the docs on clusterlabs.org. The Red Hat docs appear much more complete.

Comment: So once a monitor process has fired, it watches the resource until either it determines the resource is properly operating or timeout is reached when it flags the resource as failed?

Comment: It's all described in this chapter 20 (and all other chapters)

Comment: What you wrote was not clear initially. When the monitor *action* has fired, it should return a result as soon as it can and tell "ok" or "not ok". It's supposed to do this quickly, not keep monitoring. The looping repetition after each interval is the overall thing that keeps monitoring, not the single fired action.

Comment: That clarifies it for me. My initial concern was to avoid a sort of cascading situation where things ended up in a cat fight of sorts. I did read through the Red Hat docs you referenced and they are much more clear than those I had from pacemaker's site. Thanks kindly for your help!

Comment: I suspected your concern, that was the last bullet in my answer heh: "there won't be two overlapping monitoring actions." (but of course you can attach multiple different monitors to the same resource)